# Failed to resolve: firebase-storage-19.2.0

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

I have spent hours on it, and have also tried methods mentioned in other answers like downgrade the dependency and install the Google repository(my Android Studio doesn't show the Google repository in the SDK manager), but none of them is helpful. The error still occurs.

Here are my .gradle files, and I also mentioned the reason I have to use another maven source other than `Google()` or `maven{ url "https://maven.google.com" }`:

build.gradle (:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "comp5216.sydney.edu.au.takenshowphotos"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:25.12.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.5.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.4.0'
    // The error occurs only if I added this line
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

build.gradle(The project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- 
   projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // If I delete the maven lines, I will only get the "Cause: invalid type code: B4" error
        maven {
            url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/repositories/google'
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/repositories/jcenter'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // If I delete the maven lines, I will only get the "Cause: invalid type code: B4" error
        maven {
            url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/repositories/google'
        }
        maven {
            url 'http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/repositories/jcenter'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to Add maven { url "https://maven.google.com" } to your root level build.gradle file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Also, disable only sync the active variant option from setting>Experimental in Android Studio

[image]

Comment: I added the maven code to build.gradle file and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Good to know. Happy to help.